# Useful reformulation of Goldbach's conjecture?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, integral-equations, goldbachs-conjecture

Let us assume there exists some infinite order differential equation whose solution is:

$$ y= \sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n \exp(p_n^sx)  $$

Where $p_n$ is the $n$'th prime. Substituting $ y=\exp(\lambda x)$ as a trail solution and factorizing. The differential equation must be simplified and factorized to:

$$ \prod_{j=1}^\infty (\lambda-p_n^s) = 0$$
$$ \implies \prod_{j=1}^\infty (1-\frac{p_n^s}{\lambda}) = 0$$

Expanding the above equation:

$$\implies 1 - (\sum_{i} p_i^s)\frac{1}{\lambda} + \sum_{i < j} (p_i p_j)^s \frac{1}{\lambda^2} - \sum_{i<j<k} (p_i p_j p_k)^s \frac{1}{\lambda^3} + \dots + \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i<j<\dots<n}(-1)^n (p_i p_j \dots p_n)^s \frac{1}{\lambda^n} = 0 $$

Writing more compactly:

$$ 1+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{x_i<x_j<\dots<x_n} (p_{x_i}p_{x_j} \dots p_{x_n})^s = 0 $$

We conjecture that $\sum_{x_i<x_j<\dots<x_n} (p_{x_i}p_{x_j}\dots p_{x_n})^s $ can be analytically continued as some function of $ P(s)$ where $P(s)$ is the prime zeta function

Hence, for $f_1(P(s)) = P(s)$

And $ f_2(P(s)) = P(s)^2 - P(2s)$

And so on ...

Where $f_n(P(s))$ is given by comparing the below equation to the equation before the analytic continuation:

$$ 1 + \frac{f_1(P(s))}{\lambda} + \frac{f_2(P(s))}{\lambda^2} + \dots = 0 $$

Writing it compactly:

$$ 1 + \sum_{i}^\infty \frac{f_i(P(s))}{\lambda^s} =0  $$

Note this can be thought as of the solution of a integral:

$$ y + f_1(P(s))\int_{-\infty}^x y(x) dx +  f_2(P(s))\int_{-\infty}^x (\int_{-\infty}^k y(z) dz) dk + \dots$$

(To verify this subsitute $y=Ae^{2x}$)
Writing it compactly:

$$ y + \sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i(P(s)) \int_{- \infty}^x (\int_{- \infty}^x (\dots( \int_{- \infty}^x y dx )dx)\dots \text{$i$ times})dx) = 0  $$

### Strategy from Here

My idea was to take some asymptotic limit as $s \nearrow 1$ and rewrite this as a integral equation for $y^2$.

Since,

$$ y=\sum_{i=1}^\infty A_i \exp{p_i x}  $$

Setting $A_1=0$ and squaring:

$$ y^2 = \sum_{i,j}A_{ij}' \exp{(p_i + p_j)x} = \sum_i^\infty B'_i e^{2ix} $$

By Goldbach's conjecture the rightmost side must contain all the even powers.

### Questions

Is this a viable strategy or useful reformulation of Goldbach's conjecture? (Is it easier to show $y^2 =\sum_i^\infty B'_i e^{2ix} $as a solution)? Is the analytic continuation valid?

Comment: It seems unlikely that the desired analytic continuation exists.

Comment: I'm an outsider to this subject but doesn't the prime Zeta function satisfy it? And how did u reach that conclusion?

Comment: Your 'ansatz' is both wrong (you have the term corresponding to $p=2$ in your $y$ which means that you'll get plenty of terms in $k$ corresponding to $e^{nx}$ for odd $n$; e.g., you have a term proportional to $e^{5x}$ coming from terms of the form $e^{2x}$ and $e^{3x}$ in $y$) and not nearly enough (you need to show that all of the even coefficients of $k$ are nonzero). I don't want to rule anything out, but this looks more like complication for complication's sake than a viable path.

Comment: Would this work then? $y = Be^{3x} + C e^{5x} $ (with $A=0$) .... Then $y^2 = A' e^{6x} + B' e^{8x} + ... $ must also be a solution. Hence,  $y^2 = \frac{e^{6x}}{1- e^{2x}}$ is also a solution.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki it should be 
$y = Be^{3x} + Ce^{5x} + \dots $

Comment: This is far from my field, but I did notice that the expression after 
*"Expanding the above equation:"* is wrong. The coefficient of $\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$ should be $2\sum_{i<j}(p_ip_j)^s+\sum_{i}p_i^{2s}$. Higher order terms get more complicated accordingly. Provided that the whole product from before converges, of course.

Comment: Not sure that offering a bounty will help counterbalance the fact that there is no real question here.

Comment: @Did *"Is the analytic continuation valid?"* is a somewhat vague but valid question.

Comment: @Servaes You think so? To me, there are too many unspecified integrals and $\cdots$ to even know what the conjecture is.

Comment: @Did I do think it is a very poorly posed question, and I'm inclined to vote to close as 'unclear what you're asking'. Though maybe my complete lack of knowledge of this kind of math is to blame, which is why I cannot exclude that this might be a sensible question. Feel free to start a vote though.

Comment: @Servaes This is very honestly explained... Knowing better "this kind of math" would not change your "inclination", (un)fortunately. (As an aside, I would be curious to hear from the 4 upvoters why they think there is a question suitable to the site here, and even, a good one...)

Comment: @Did It's an integral equation whose solution is given by $y= Ae^{4x} + \dots$ so it doesn't matter that there are no boundary conditions given ... As there will be constants in the equation

Comment: @Servaes The preceeding step was wrong .. It's not been edited

Comment: @AnantSaxena Sorry but what is "it" in "It's an integral equation"? (That you had to change several times your question is not a good sign.)

Comment: Sorry about that (I just changed it again to make things clearer) ... The integral equation is the equation above "Questions"

Comment: If ever you embarked on the task of clarifying the $$\cdots$$ in this equation, to make precise the bounds of integration and to get rid of some annoying repeated variables ($dxdx$, oh my...), then and only then might all this reach the status of being an acceptable question. I know that this is hard, this is called doing mathematics... (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Comment: @Did I have completely edited the question ... Hopefully it is more readable now?

Comment: Unfortunately your post raises tons of problems. Starting at the top of your post, why do you think that, correcting a typo, the condition $$ \prod_{n=1}^\infty (\lambda-p_n^s) = 0$$ is equivalent to the fact that there exists some $n$ such that $$\lambda=p_n^s\ ?$$ Note, for example, that $$ \prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(\lambda-\frac{n}{n+1}\right) = 0$$ if $\lambda=0$ although $0\ne\frac{n}{n+1}$ for every $n\geqslant1$. That you use such (wrong) equivalences without suspecting that infinite products **do not** behave entirely like finite products is annoying, to say the least. ...

Comment: ... To go further, once the problem I just raised would be solved, one should explain the range of the parameter $s$ one considers, and what is the meaning of $$ \prod_{n=1}^\infty (\lambda-p_n^s)$$ when $\lambda\ne p_n^s$ for every $n$. And so on... (And we discussed only the first lines of your question.)

Comment: @DId I'm only assuming there exists a partial differential equation whose solution when $y = \exp(\lambda x)$ factorized can be written as $ \prod_{n=1}^\infty (\lambda - p_n)^s$ ... Maybe I'm not understanding what you mean ...

Comment: It is stunning how you seem to be systematically lost when people raise precise, specific (and rather simple), **mathematical points** about your posts. Sorry but what is unclear in the point I raise in my previous comment?

Comment: @Did Wait all of a sudden it made sense to me ... Can I then start directly from the $\prod_{n} (1 - p_n^s/\lambda^s)$ and claim $y = \sum_{n}A_n \exp{(p_n^s x)}$ is a solution?

Comment: @AnantSaxena I suggest you ask separate questions for the specific issues raised in the comments, maybe then things will clarify.